# How to efficiently apply function over each row of ndarray with value from list of args?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I would like to apply function `func` over each row of 2D ndarray `arr` shaped `n` x `m` with provided list of arguments `args` (of lengh `n`). That is for each row `i` function is executed as `func(arr[i, :], args[i])`.

This task can be acomplished with `np.fromiter` (using for loop):

```
iterable = (func(row, arg) for row, arg in zip(arr, args))
results = np.fromiter(iterable, dtype=int)
```

However this can take some time in case of large arrays. Acoording to [unutbu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22581833/17665627) using numpy's python utility functions (e.g. `np.apply_along_axis`) does not provide siginifacnt speedup. Is there a way to optimize this process?

To avoid falling into XY problem trap, beneath is my orginal problem statement:

I have an ndarray representing image, shaped `n` x `m`. This image undergo processing during, which for each row a specifix index `i` is calculated. I want to compose a image of orginal shape (`n` x `m`) using data on the right from index `i` for each row. That is I want to resample each `row[i:]` of length `m - i` to `m` samples. Note that I want to use my own implementation of resampling function (don't want to use `scipy.signal.resample` etc).

EDIT:

Test code with func example (added `count` argument to `fromiter` as suggested by LudvigH):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def simple_slant_range_correction(
    row, height, n_samples, max_ground_range, max_slant_range, slant_range_resolution
):
    ground_ranges = np.linspace(height, max_ground_range, n_samples)
    slant_ranges = np.sqrt(ground_ranges ** 2 + height ** 2)
    slant_ranges_indicies = slant_ranges / slant_range_resolution - 1
    slant_ranges_indicies_floor = np.floor(slant_ranges_indicies).astype(np.int16)
    slant_ranges_indicies_ceil = np.clip(
        0, n_samples - 1, slant_ranges_indicies_floor + 1
    )
    weight = slant_ranges_indicies - slant_ranges_indicies_floor
    return (
        weight * row[slant_ranges_indicies_ceil]
        + (1 - weight) * row[slant_ranges_indicies_floor]
    ).astype(np.float32)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Test parameters
    n, m = 100, 100
    max_slant_range = 50
    slant_range_resolution = max_slant_range / m

    # Create some dummy data
    data = np.zeros((n, m))
    h_indicies = np.ones((n), dtype=int)
    for i in np.arange(0, n, 5):
        data[:i, :i] += i
        h_indicies[:i] += 1
    heights = h_indicies * slant_range_resolution
    max_ground_ranges = np.sqrt(max_slant_range ** 2 - heights ** 2)
    # Perform resampling based on h_index
    iters = (
        simple_slant_range_correction(
            row, height, m, max_ground_range, max_slant_range, slant_range_resolution
        )
        for row, height, max_ground_range in zip(data, heights, max_ground_ranges)
    )
    data_sampled = np.fromiter(iters, dtype=np.dtype((np.float32, m)), count=n)

    # Plot data
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2)
    axs[0].plot(h_indicies + 0.5, np.arange(n) + 0.5, c="red")
    axs[0].imshow(data, vmin=0, vmax=data.max())
    axs[1].imshow(data_sampled, vmin=0, vmax=data.max())
    axs[0].set_axis_off()
    axs[1].set_axis_off()
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Please include the code for `func`.

Comment: In `numpy` "vectorization" just means applying compiled methods to the whole array.  Short of doing your own compiling, such as with `cython` or `numba` there isn't a way of significantly speeding up row by row iterations.  `numpy` cannot compile your python resampling function.  The bulk of the run time for iterating on N rows comes from simply calling that function N times.

Comment: @mpw2 I included sample code. @hpaulj thanks for the answer, I'll check `numba` and `cython`

Comment: What is the speedup for using the `count` argument to fromiter in your case? Currently you do a LOT of memory allocations, which is expensive like ****

Comment: If you make the allocations upfront, and the algorithm itself is somewhat cheap to compute (I assume your interpolation is fast in itself since that is your expertise... look into e.g. numba to compile it), the next thing to do is to paralellize the vectorization. How many CPU cores do you have, and do you have any GPUs available?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of specifying `count` argument, it provided about 10% speed up (on some dummy data). I'll look into numbda

Answer (score 1):

It is typically faster to take advantage of vectorization by using numpy operations to manipulate the data, as compared to using python functions and objects to manipulate the data. Below is an example of a way to solve the problem described at the end of your question using numpy vectorization.

```
import numpy as np
```

Choosing some array and column indices as an example:

```
#     1 2 3 3                  1
# A = 4 5 6 6    row_indices = 3
#     7 8 9 9                  2

A = np.array([[1,2,3,3],[4,5,6,6],[7,8,9,9]])
row_indices = np.array([1,3,2])
```

Use vector operations to build a boolean masking array and then multiply the original array by the mask:

```
NM = np.shape(A)
N = NM[0]
M = NM[1]
col = np.arange(M,dtype=np.uint32)
B = np.outer(np.ones([1,N],dtype=np.uint32),col)
C = np.outer(row_indices,np.ones([1,M],dtype=np.uint32))

A_sampled = (B>=C)*A

print(A_sampled)

# output:
#   0 2 3 3
#   0 0 0 6
#   0 0 9 9
```